# What is apiSecret in the Nuxt env file?

Tags: nuxt.js, api-key, env-file

What is the purpose of setting NUXT_API_SECRET in the .env file within a Nuxt project?

We include the line `NUXT_API_SECRET` in the env file in production stage, essentially representing an API key, correct? In the nuxt.config.ts file, we configure it as per the practices outlined in the Nuxt [official documentation](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/runtime-config).

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  runtimeConfig: {
    // Private keys are only available on the server
    apiSecret: process.env.NUXT_API_SECRET,
    // Public keys that are exposed to the client
    public: {
      apiBase: process.env.NUXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE
    }
  },
}
```

When discussing APIs with backend colleagues using the Postman interface, we all know to place the access token in the header bearer and do not need to include the API KEY.

When I asked my supervisor how this `apiSecret` variable should be generated, they clarified, "The `apiSecret` is not related to the backend; it's something the frontend needs to handle."

I am unsure if my current understanding is correct; please provide some feedback:

1. The Nuxt official documentation informs us that `runtimeConfig` has private and public parts. By following the official configuration and placing it in the private section, the API key will not be exposed in the browser. Hence, it's normal not to see the API key in the browser console's network section.
2. Currently, our API authentication is handled by the access token, not the API key. According to [this article](https://www.gomomento.com/blog/api-keys-vs-tokens-whats-the-difference), the API key is used to identify "this app," but it can be  entirely unrelated to API permissions. Therefore, I can generate an `apiSecret` using my own method without involving any issues related to API authorization.

Additionally, my other concerns are:

1. I cannot see the API key in the request headers of the browser console; I can only see the access token/refresh token. However, does the backend still receive the API key? Does my frontend server send the API key when sending requests to the backend server?
2. Assuming the API key is no longer related to calling the API, why is it still necessary to include the API key in our env file?

Big thanks to anyone who is willing to help with answers and feedback!

Comment: Your Nuxt app wants to do things on the backend. The backend needs to allow those modifications only to trusted frontends, hence they handshake with an "API secret" (whatever the name you give to it). You need to hide it to the client-side, so that you cannot just go to your website and see it written in the source-code (inspectable for any frontend apps) or in the network tab. Using it on the server-side (hence putting it as a nuxt private key is the way. The exact name of the token etc really doesn't matter that much, just put the string where needed based on your backend's team feedback.

Comment: Lastly, when using JWT authentication you will have some idea of access/refresh token indeed. Those are initiated to let you handle communication with the backend. Refresh token keeping the access one alive every few minutes or so. Purpose being to have something secure enough, so that the backend constantly checks if you're a trusted frontend. The point is to mostly have a middleman handling the private exchange securely. The JWT tokens are public and that's totally fine this way, it's similar to an SSH public key. For the details of the API key, just talk to the backend team they know better